# github ssh problem- permission denied(publickey)

Tags: ssh, git, openssh

I tried setting up git as shown in [Github's help page](http://help.github.com/linux-set-up-git/), on Arch linux but there seems to be some problem with the SSH keys. It gives this error-

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

This problem is documented in the [troubleshooting page](http://help.github.com/troubleshooting-ssh/) but I when I tried the procedure shown there, it didn't really solve the problem. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have set the correct permissions on your `~/.ssh` folder.

`$ chmod go-w ~/.ssh`

See: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Using_SSH_Keys